# Singleton как область видимости Spring бинов по умолчанию. Причина

Tags: spring, scope

связан ли тот факт, что singleton - Spring bean scope by default с тем обстоятельством, что обычно бины stateless?

Прошу разъяснений о возможной взаимосвязи состояния бина (statefull, stateless) с его областью видимости.